# understanding a line from canvas app js (or possibly jquery), checking for radio type not working with additional element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, canvas

```js
function mouseDragged(){
  let type = _("#pen-pencil").checked?"pencil":"brush";
  ...
}
```

```html
    <div class="type">
      <input type="radio" name="pen-type" id="pen-pencil" checked>
      <label for="pen-pencil">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </label>
      <input type="radio" name="pen-type" id="pen-brush">
      <label for="pen-brush">
        <i class="fa fa-paint-brush" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </label>
      ...
```

I'm trying to create a JS canvas app myself (still am a newbie to javascript and app dev) and was looking at this specific code that uses p5.js and font-awesome (relevant excerpts above). This is an excerpt from someone else's code that I found quite useful in that the code allows me to switch between brush/pencil—and I thought to add on 'eraser' as shown below, but it seems the jQuery checked? only accepts two arguments (like pencil and brush as shown in the first example; please correct me if I'm wrong). So I was wondering if there'd be a way similar to checked? that can have three elements—any help would be really appreciated!

```js
function mouseDragged(){
  let type = _("#pen-pencil").checked?"pencil":"brush":"eraser";
  let size = parseInt(_("#pen-size").value);
  let color = _("#pen-color").value;
  fill(color);
  stroke(color);
  if(type == "eraser"){
    erase(size, size)
  }
  if(type == "pencil"){
    strokeWeight(3);
    line(pmouseX, pmouseY, mouseX, mouseY);
  } else {
    strokeWeight(size);
    line(pmouseX, pmouseY, mouseX, mouseY);
  } 
}
...
```

```html
    <div class="type">
      <input type="radio" name="pen-type" id="pen-pencil" checked>
      <label for="pen-pencil">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </label>
      <input type="radio" name="pen-type" id="pen-brush">
      <label for="pen-brush">
        <i class="fa fa-paint-brush" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </label>
      <input type="radio" name="pen-type" id="pen-eraser" checked>
      <label for="pen-eraser">
        <i class="fa fa-eraser" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you fix the unexpected token : error message in your snippet?

Comment: @FSDford oh um I'm not sure where you get that error from—do you mean you need the entirety of the code?